# FileZilla won't upload properly

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I recently installed WordPress on my hosting server and all went fine, however one of my pages "/wp-admin/update-core.php" is having issues. Upon opening, the file appears to be cut off mid way.

I've compared this file against the file in the zip file I uploaded and the original copy is not truncated.

Where this gets even weirder is that, if I edit the file on the server to paste in the missing code, after I save and open again, the file is still missing the code I just added AND is now missing an additional line of code.

I've also tried deleting the file, and re-uploading the original copy again and it appears to be cutting off at the same point.

Anyone experienced this or have any ideas?

Comment: The fact that you can't manually edit the file(s) suggests that you don't have the relevant permissions to save the file after overriding it. How are you editing it? Are you using vi / nano with sudo? Have you checked the permissions, or tried taking ownership of them?

Comment: @PhillHealey Hi Phil, I'm uploading and editing using FileZilla FTP Client, which lets me edit the file on server using Notepad++ on my machine. I considered a permissions issue, but very odd that it uploads half the PHP file for a single file out of thousands.

Comment: Filezilla only lets you edit locally. It downloads the file to your pc, opens it in your chosen editor then uploads it again when saved. However, the file won't actually overwrite your server copy if the permissions dont allow it. FileZilla, has no knowledge of what happens to the file once it hands it over to the server. Can you delete the file on the server via Filezilla? If so, delete it, wait a few mins then refresh your view in Filezilla and make sure the file is gone. Then upload the file again.

Answer (score 2):

I've got a similar problem with v3.37.3 - uploaded .zip file is truncated, and .svg files have zero length. This is true even when I set the transfer type to 'binary' rather than 'auto'. Also, when repeating the copy operation for the .zip file, I am prompted more than once to confirm the overwrite of th eexisting file, almost as though Filezilla sees several files instead of just the one .zip archive.

Comment: Same here for a .dmg file. Half of the file is uploaded and then FileZilla asks me to overwrite the file with the other half. It turns out I exceeded the DISK QUOTA mid upload and the other end was doing something to cause this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I uploaded a file (a Linux executable) and it was truncated from 4,396,728 bytes to 4,392,145 bytes. My fix was to **change the transfer type, which you can set using the Transfer menu, from Auto to Binary**. I guess that FileZilla assumes that files with no extension are text; other files, with extensions dmg (Apple disk image) and zip (compressed file) were correctly treated as binary. I am using a very recent version of FileZilla: 3.29.0.